# Оператор Case - как реализовать срабатывание второго оператора. Хотя бы оператора присвоения?

Tags: delphi, case

Допустим есть обычный оператор `case`

```
case a of
  1 : ShowMessage('a=1');
  2 : ShowMessage('a=2');
  3 : ShowMessage('a=3');
  4 : ShowMessage('a=4');
else ShowMessage('no');
end;
```

Возможно ли как-то реализовать такую конструкцию:

```
case a of
  1 : ShowMessage('a=1'); b:=10; 
  2 : ShowMessage('a=2'); b:=20;
  3 : ShowMessage('a=3'); b:=30;
  4 : ShowMessage('a=4'); b:=40;
else ShowMessage('no');
end;
```

Вот что-то подобное, так как после выполнения условия `a:=1;` необходимо присвоить переменной `b` некоторое значение.

---

P.S. Или каким способом здесь можно решить ситуцию, не переводя `case` в `if`?

Comment: Это базовый синтаксис: составной оператор, он же `begin..end`. После двоеточия ставите `begin`, потом свой код, потом `end;` (с точкой с запятой)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
case a of
  1 : 
      begin
          ShowMessage('a=1'); 
          b:=10; 
      end;
  2 : 
      begin
          ShowMessage('a=2'); 
          b:=20;
      end;
  3 : 
      begin
         ShowMessage('a=3'); 
         b:=30;
      end;
  4 : 
      begin
         ShowMessage('a=4'); 
         b:=40;
      end;
  else ShowMessage('no');
end;
```

Comment: исправил, поспешил вначале

Comment: Спасибо! Я и так всё понял сразу с комментария @kami.
Только вот деоптимизация какая-то получается. `case` на 2 страницы теперь у меня распух с SQL запросами!

Comment: деоптимизация была бы, если бы код стал медленней выполняться. А это просто издержки форматирования, вдобавок, если есть большие участки под `begin...end` в кейсах, можно вынести их в отдельные ф-ции

Comment: @I_CaR вынесите весь код из элементов case во вложенные функции. Если SQL-запрос отличается только параметрами - его можно вынести в константу и использовать Format. Ну и так далее. Способов оптимизации кода для просмотра - куча, включая {$REGION XXX}

Comment: Не забудьте установить какое-нибудь значение `b` в случае отрабатывания ветки `else` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Для приведенного кода `case` не нужен вообще

```
if a in [1..4] then begin
  ShowMessageFmt('a=%d', [a]);
  b := a * 10;
end else
  ShowMessage('no');
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один возможный (и более короткий, если пар много) вариант, если у вас объявлен тип или диапазон значений `a` - воспользоваться массивом констант:

```
type
  TPresetType = record Text: string; Value: Integer; end;
const
  PRESETS: array [1..4] of TPresetType = (
    (Text: '=10'; Value: 10),
    (Text: '=20'; Value: 20),
    (Text: '=30'; Value: 30),
    (Text: '=40'; Value: 40)
  );
begin
  if a >= Low(PRESETS) and a <= High(PRESETS) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(PRESETS[a].Text);
    b := PRESETS[a].Value; 
  end else
    ShowMessage('no');
end;
```

или почти идентично, но без типа рекорда, с 2 массивами констант:

```
const
  PRESET_TEXT: array [1..4] of string = ('=10', '=20', '=30', '=40');
  PRESET_VALUE: array [1..4] of Integer = (10, 20, 30, 40);
begin
  if a >= Low(PRESET_TEXT) and a <= High(PRESET_TEXT) then 
  begin
    ShowMessage(PRESET_TEXT[a]);
    b := PRESET_VALUE[a]; 
  end else
    ShowMessage('no');
end;
```

В чем плюсы такого решения - снижение возможности ошибиться:

- Перечисление всех вариантов и значений в 1 месте
- Если вы можете выделить тип переменной `a` (например `a: TTextAlign;` даст записать `PRESET_TEXT: array [a] of string`), то при добавлении нового значения компилятор вынудит вас дополнить ВСЕ значения.